# Upper bound on the norm of the fundamental matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, normed-spaces

Consider the following linear and non-autonomous o.d.e
$\dot{x}(t) = A(t) x(t)$

I am interested in knowing an upper bound on the norm of the fundamental matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_matrix_(linear_differential_equation)) for this o.d.e.

Comment: Without knowing any details about the system, I can only recommend to take a look at Philippe Hartman's book on ODEs. Maybe you can find what you need there.

Comment: Are you looking for something like $\exp(\int_0^t \|A(s)\|\,ds)$? Apply Grönwall lemma for $\|\dot X(t)\|\le\|A(t)\|·\|X(t)\|$.